# dompdf Stylesheet Errors

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, dompdf

So I am using https://github.com/chrisnharvey/CodeIgniter-PDF-Generator-Library/wiki to easily make PDF's on my system.

I am also using bootstrap. Now when I run the code, my styles dont' get extracted. And I get the following error:

```
Illegal string offset 'hex'
```

If I remove my stylesheets, I don't get the error but nothing is styled.

I am loading my styles like so:

```
<link href="http://the-green-panda.org/themes/admin/Adminica/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://the-green-panda.org/themes/admin/Adminica/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I did enable remote in the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```

Has anyone else used this codeigniter library and successfully linked style sheets to make the pdf's look nicer?

Comment: Hello anyone out there?

Comment: Try updating to dompdf 0.6.1 if you're not already there. There was a patch in that version [relating to hex colors](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/749).